# Tourist visa for Suriname for an Indian Citizen?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, suriname

After some discussions, I found out that Caribbean Hindustani is quite popular in Suriname. This has inclined me to choose it as one of the next destinations on my bucket list.

How can I get a tourist visa for Suriname as an Indian citizen?

In my discussions, I have heard that it allows visa on arrival. Is this the case or a visa prior to arrival is required? If yes, can I get it from an Embassy/Consulate in the United States?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Suriname Embassy in the United States](http://www.surinameembassy.org/visa_extension.shtml) there is still visa required for Indian Citizens, though it will be less expensive then for the US citizens.

As far as I can tell Visa On arrival is available [for business purposes only](http://scgmia.com/special-categories-visa/) with no further details an restrictions on countries have been made available:

> 1. **VISA AT ARRIVAL**: THIS VISA IS FOR BUSINESS ONLY. THE APPLICATION AND FEES ARE DONE IN SURINAME

There is a [Tourist Card](http://scgmia.com/the-tourist-card/) which one can purchase at [Johan Adolf Pengel airport / Zanderij / Suriname](http://scgmia.com/faq-visa/) but again it's not available for Indian Citizens.  So as you indicated in another one of your questions: more visas for you.

Comment: More visas for me. Hmm. :(

Comment: Update: link of scgmia.com has expired, and there is mention that the visa office at the airport might be closed as of August 2019. I got my visa at [VFS Global](https://suriname.vfsevisa.com/suriname/online/home/e-tourist-card) which is the official partner of the Ministry of Foreign Affairs.

Comment: Been there in September 2019 and the VISA office at the airport was still open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes tourist card is available for Indian also . You can take that after arrival at Suriname also.

Comment: Can you add a source for that? The @Karlson answer does not confirm it, nor do the details provided by the Suriname Embassy in Delhi http://www.surinameembassy.in/visa.html